# Arduino - What does NO_KEY mean and do?

Tags: types, arduino, keypad

I am trying to make a calculator project with an LCD and keypad but in order to do that I need to know what NO_KEY means.

```
void loop() {
  char customKey = keypad.getKey();
  
  if (customKey != NO_KEY)
  {
    Serial.println(customKey);
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what it could do?

Normally, without it the Serial monitor spits the right key but is flickering back and forth?

When I add this line in, it magically works.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `keypad.getKey()` method. This means that every frame, you asking to see what the key pressed on the keypad is, even if a key isn't being pressed. If there is not a key being pressed, then it will give the value of `NO_KEY`.

One way to integrate this is this:

```
if (keypad.getKey() != NO_KEY)
{
    // The code here will run whenever there is a key pressed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it means nothing has been pressed.
every cycle of the loop the arduino "get" the current character that waits in the buffer.
if there is no waiting character the `keypad.getKey()` will return `NO_KEY`.

**why should you use this?** 
`keypad.getKey()`

> Returns the key that is pressed, if any. This function is
> non-blocking.

that means your arduino won't get suck till key pressed. (unlike `waitForKey()`)

[more here](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Keypad/)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, my friend has told me why this is needed.

Essentially, the getKey function always gives a character response no matter what, meaning when no key is pressed it will post in the serial monitor as a space, hence the flickering.

Now it will only post if it is not equal to no key.

Great, time to move on with the rest of the project!